# grep question͏͏

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm currently stuck on a question for my Unix course that requires us to search for any words that have the following characteristics. I was wondering if anyone could assist in crafting such a command, as it's far more convoluted than anything I've done before. The characteristics for a word in the English language are as follows.

It must ...

1. be exactly 5 characters long
2. begin with an upper or lowercase vowel (a, e, i, o, u, or y)
3. have a lowercase 't' in the middle position.
4. end with a lowercase 's'
5. The rest of the characters can be any character that occur in English words; i.e, uppercase, lowercase, hyphen, numbers, etc.

So far I've gotten something like this.

`[aeiouy].t.s`

within brackets and such. 
All of this must be using grep and use `/usr/share/dict/words` to find what the command reads. 
I just need to know what parameters to use. Pretty dang confusing.

The main issue I'm finding is ensuring the first character is uppercase OR lowercase, whilst ensuring the remaining characters can be interchangeable as uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: Why not just use `[aeiouyAEIOUY]`?

Comment: Note that `.` will also match on things like space or `<`, `?` which usually don't occur in English words

Comment: That works as well, but for whatever reason I'm also having trouble ensuring it stays as only 5 characters. I've done grep "^[aeiouyAEIOUY].t.s" and it ends up giving me words like Estes's or "Abbott's" which it shouldn't be.

Comment: Use `grep -x '[aeiouyAEIOUY].t.s'` or use *both* the `^` (matches at start of subject) and `$` (end of subject) anchors.

Comment: I am a little confused by the question: "ensure that it is any case" or "allow any case"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/dict/words` has one word per line.

The main thing you are missing are the *anchors* to match the beginning and/or end of the word. As words are one per line, you can use `^` and `$` which match the start and end of string (line).

```
grep '^[AEIOUYaeiouy].t.s$' /usr/dict/words
```

Lots of versions of regular expression tools have extensions to allow word boundaries, e.g.,

```
grep '\<[AEIOUYaeiouy].t.s\>' /usr/dict/words
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I knew I was missing something like that, I'd been using ^ to start a line but hadn't used $ and ended up getting words that were too big or too small.

Comment: "too big" I can understand, "too small" puzzles me.

Comment: I'd forgot to add brackets on that specific instance. I was trying everything I could think of.

Comment: Using `-w` would be more portable than using `\<`, `>`, however note that there is a word boundary between `-` and `a` in `minus-altus` for instance (IOW, the definition of *word character* is not the same between `grep`'s `-w`/`\<`/`\>` and the OP's).

Comment: You have to practice this yourself. There are good regex tools out there. Including some on-line ones. Play with them, practice, learn.

Comment: The question says `The rest of the characters can be any character that occur in english words` so those shouldn't be `.`s in the regexp as those would match punctuation characters like `;` or a literal period, `.`. Maybe each `.` in the regexp should be `[[:alnum:]_-]` given the OPs further definition of `i.e, uppercase, lowercase, hyphen, numbers, etc.` though idk what else `etc.` might be intended to include.

Comment: @EdMorton Given that this is a question which is about matching things in /usr/share/dict/words, is for a unix course, and the answer is more complex than anything that has been done before,  I believe that you don't want to overthink the answer. For example I didn't worry about setting the locale. Using `[[:alnum:]]` might mean using characters that are alphabetic but not used in english, for example Thai.

Comment: English can very occasionally include characters such æ and ï

Answer (score 0):

```
 grep "^[aeiouAEIOU].t.s\b" filename
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).